# CodeIgniter order_by statement with a dynamic value

Tags: codeigniter, sql-order-by

I have a utility in php that fetches data from our database based on the fields I choose. Now I want to sort the fetched results with any field that I type in the textbox for instance I retrieved:

**student.name, student.gr, student.class_id, student.father_name**

Now I type in the textbox I have with the name sort_order to sort the fetched result by student.gr so I type:

**'student.gr', 'desc'**

and the order_by statement on the result page is like

**$this->db->order_by($sort_order);**

Why does not it work ?

Comment: Does it work when you leave out the quotes and comma for the text you're typing into the `sort_order` textbox, like this: `student.gr desc` ?
You seem to be using the syntax for using `order_by` with 2 parameters, but since you're only passing one parameter to the method,
you probably need to be using the syntax as in the second example here (no quotes and no comma if ordering by a single field):
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results

Comment: Dear Marleen, you just hit nail on the head. :)) It worked like a charm. Thanks a million.